# Trouble combining certain arrays in Perl(web::scraper)

Tags: perl, web-scraping

So, I'm trying to learn Perl in my spare time, and I've watched a lot of tutorials and read some material on it.

I'm trying to combine these arrays,(Not that I cut out some of the other scraper blocks for brevity, they are tested and work, and resemble the PCMAG scraper given)

```
#PCMAG
my $pcmag1_items = scraper {
    process ".news-content", "pcmag1_items[]" => scraper {
        process "h3", title => 'TEXT';
        process "p", body => 'TEXT';
        process ".time-stamp", date => 'TEXT';
        process 'a', link => '@href';   
    };  
};
my $pcmag2_items = scraper {
    process ".news-reviews > ul > li", "pcmag2_items[]" => scraper {
        process "h3", title => 'TEXT';
        process "p", body => 'TEXT';
        process ".time-stamp", date => 'TEXT';
        process 'a', link => '@href';   
    };  
};
my $pcmag1_res = $pcmag1_items->scrape( URI->new("http://www.pcmag.com/news"));
my $pcmag2_res = $pcmag2_items->scrape( URI->new("http://www.pcmag.com/news"));


#MAIN
my @items = (@{$pcmag1_res->{pcmag1_items}}, @{$pcmag2_res->{pcmag2_items}}, @{$cnn_res->{cnn_items}}, @{$cnet_res->{cnet_items}});

for my $item (@items) {
    print "$item->{title} $item->{body} $item->{date} (link: $item->{link})\n \n";
}
```

the error I get is:

```
greg@Linux:~/Desktop/Perl$ perl scraper2.pl
Use of uninitialized value $xpath in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/Web/Scraper.pm line 136.
'' doesn't look like a valid XPath expression: Not a _primary_expr at 
greg@Linux:~/Desktop/Perl$
```

Comment: When I run your code with the `#MAIN` simplified to `my @items = (@{$pcmag1_res->{pcmag1_items}}, @{$pcmag2_res->{pcmag2_items}});`, I get new warnings at all, so perhaps it's referring to the part building `$cnn_res` and `$cnet_res`.

Comment: New warnings? or do you mean no warnings? Also, ran all these scrapers and printed them without combining they worked. Wait, I think you helped me find the problem..

Comment: Yes, I meant no warnings.  And congrats on finding the solution.  `"Stackoverflow, helping you through accidental inspiration."`  Works for me.

Comment: You pretty much gave me the answer honestly, work like a charm now, thanks again